# forked child process hangs in node.js

Tags: node.js, fork, child-process

I've faced some problems with child_process fork, I guess It's like stdio.

after I fork by some js code, child works that request streaming data and then receives data the, just through data to parent.
when I added logs into child, after log "Count[1503]" stops. 
(I am not sure in your case also 1499, but exactly same data however manytimes you try)

I just make sample code below
(excute test.js)

// test.js

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    child_process = require('child_process');

app.listen(3030, function() {
    console.log('service started');
});

var child = child_process.fork(__dirname + '/test_child.js', [], { silent: true });

child.on('exit', function(code, signal) {
    console.log('exit\n', code, signal);
})
```

// test_child.js

```
var winston = require('winston'),
    logger = new winston.Logger({
        level: 'silly',
        transports: [
            new (winston.transports.File)({
                name: 'mainLog',
                filename: 'child_test.log',
                level: 'silly'
            }),
            new (winston.transports.Console)({
                colorize: true,
            })
        ]
    });


var interval = 2,
    cnt = 1,
    count = 1;

setInterval(function() {
    logger.info('Count[%d]', count++);
}, interval)
setInterval(function() {
    logger.info('CNT[%d]', cnt++);
}, interval)
```

the reason why I guess it's about stdio related buffer is when I add some text as log, log Count is going to short.

please help me who are aware of node.js

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass `silent: true` to `child_process.fork()`, pipes are used between the parent and child. In your parent script you are never reading from the child's streams (especially stdout), so at some point the internal buffer is filling up and the built-in backpressure mechanism causes the process to stop accepting output from the child.

Add something like this to your parent script to keep the streams flowing and it should work as expected:

```
child.stdout.resume();
child.stderr.resume();
```

That particular will simply ignore the output. If you need the output, you should add `'data'` event handlers or make sure to call `.read()` on the streams often.

Comment: Thanks you so much! I hadn't found flush stream buffer, even I guess stream buffer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! this helped me solve a very mysterious bug in my system. Didn't realize this kind of problem can occur by not consuming the piped stdout.